# Does crossing your eyes to see stereoscopic images provide the same effect as unfocusing your eyes (looking into the distance)?

Tags: optics, vision

Not sure if this is the best place to post this. Please correct any formatting/grammatical errors I've made!

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?  What results did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the depths are reversed. The reason is that in free fusion (looking at the distance) each eye sees the image that correspond to its own side, that is, the left eye sees the left image and the right eye sees the right image, whereas in crossfusing (crossing your eyes), each eye sees the image on the opposite side, that is, the left eye sees the right image and the right eye sees the left image. This reverses the sign of the relative disparity between corresponding image points, which causes the depth to be interpreted by the brain with the reverse sign too. For instance, if during free fusion you see a small square floating in front of a small square, during cross fusion you will see the small square farther away than the larger one.

Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binocular_disparity

Comment: Thanks, this answered the question. Gotta love when a Wikipedia article exists that is literally the answer to your question.